# Testing Emacs Lisp Code Involving Org Mode

Tags: ert, testing

I'm trying to figure out how I can use ERT and libraries like [el-mock](https://github.com/rejeep/el-mock.el) to test simple functions that manipulate my org-document.

Consider a function like this:

```
(defun promote-next-heading ()
  (org-next-visible-heading 1)
  (org-metaright))
```

How would I write a test for this? Should I have a .org file dedicated for tests like these? And then when the headline gets promoted, how do I confirm this? And then revert it for the next test?

While the example above is contrived, I'm writing quite a few functions that manipulate or query my org document, and I really would feel better if I could test for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is by string comparisons, e.g.

```
(require 'ert)

(ert-deftest test-1 ()
  (should
   (string=
    (with-temp-buffer
      (org-mode)
      (insert "

* test heading
")
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (promote-next-heading)
      (buffer-string))
    "

** test heading
")))
```

You could also have content in files and do it like this:

```
(ert-deftest test-2 ()
  (should
   (string=
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert-file-contents "ref-1.org")
      (org-mode)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (my-promote-next-heading)
      (buffer-string))
    ;; this file is what the transformed text should look like.
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert-file-contents "ref-2.org")
      (buffer-string)))))
```

You run the tests with M-x ert

Comment: I don't find it an elegant solution, however, at the moment I think it serves my purposes. I wish Org Mode had functions that took in text rather than rely on where my point is - leads to a lot of boilerplate in my tests: Creating buffers, moving the point, etc. Perhaps I can abstract it into a function/macro.

Comment: you might find some abstractions at https://repo.or.cz/org-mode.git/tree/HEAD:/testing 

For some reason these aren't on my load path, or I would have pointed to them.